# Segmentation fault while trying to get texture region

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, kivy

I have created a simple function, returning a region of a texture from given image:

```
from kivy.core.image import Image


def get_figure_texture(figure: Figure, img_path: str):
image = Image(img_path).texture
figures = {
    'white': {
        'king': (0, 0),
        'queen': (64, 0),
        'rook': (128, 0),
        'knight': (192, 0),
        'bishop': (256, 0),
        'pawn': (320, 0)
    },
    'black': {
        'king': (0, 64),
        'queen': (64, 64),
        'rook': (128, 64),
        'knight': (192, 64),
        'bishop': (256, 64),
        'pawn': (320, 64)
    }
}
offset = figures[figure.color_name][figure.name]

return image.texture.get_region(offset[0], offset[1], 64, 64)
```

Then, I want to create a texture:

```
 figure = Figure
 figure.name = 'king'
 figure.color_name = 'white'
 figure.texture - get_figure_texture(figure, 'res/figures.png')
```

And when Kivy tries to create image from given path, I get this in log:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in 
/home/celtic/.kivy/logs/kivy_18-03-04_7.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.3 (default, Oct  3 2017, 21:45:48) 
[GCC 7.2.0]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pygame, 
img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
/home/celtic/PycharmProjects/pygame-
tutorial/venv/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: 
ImportWarning: can't resolve package from __spec__ or __package__, 
falling back on __name__ and __path__
return f(*args, **kwds)
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
```

The image is 384 x 128 and the path I provide is correct, because for other path I get error:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tell'`.

Comment: if you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve], and your code is not, I have patched it and it does not generate that error, so it is probably in another part of your code, make an effort and we will help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Kivy's pygame backend is deprecated, try using sdl2.
2. If this is a good representation of your actual code, try adding `from kivy.core.window import Window` at the top.